# Cacheable principle of REST Architecture Implementation on Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, rest

One of the principles of REST architecture: Cacheable

How to sign response message on Controller API method as cacheable for Client in Spring Boot project.

> Cacheable: The cacheable constraint requires that a response should implicitly or explicitly label itself as cacheable or non-cacheable. If the response is cacheable, the client application gets the right to reuse the response data later for equivalent requests and a specified period.

Comment: This principle doesn't specifically dictate that caching must be configured at the controller level in your application. It's more appropriate to implement caching on the service layer since database interactions are expensive. It's also not always appropriate though and depends on the exact use case.